How can give in Model class property automatically filled up hyphen after 3 digits in phone number validation
I have a model class called PhoneNumber.cs as view model and it is being used as globally for entering the phone number. How can I restrict the user to enter 10 numeric digits only without any special character or alphabets. Also after 3 digits , it should be automatically filled up with '-' .For example if the user type phone number and after each 3 digits, hypen should be filled, 123-456-7890.
PhoneNumber.cs
public string PhoneNumber {get;set}

Here is the code I applied to javascript. But the problem is it fills two dashed after first 3 digits . it look like 123--456-890.
<script>
    $("#numberInput").on('input', function(event) {
        var input = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, ''); // Remove non-numeric characters
        var formattedInput = input.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})?(\d*)/, '$1-$2$3'); // Insert hyphen after the 3rd and 6th digits
        $(this).val(formattedInput);
    });
</script>


That's usually handled by the UI. you can validate the data that arrives to that property using Data annotations. You can try searching "Masking input in ASP.NET".

You can use Data Annotation validations to validate mobile number.
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
[StringLength(10, MinimumLength=10)]
[RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid phone number")]
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

So above validations will check the 10 digit along with - after 3rd character

How can I mask in in html view page script after typing after 3 digits automatically fill-up dashes . For example 111-222-3333

@Alevel data annotation will do it automatically. You have to add @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)

If you want to use js to achieve this requirement, I suggest you could try below codes:
It will just allow 10 digits and put two slash between them.
<input type="text" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="Enter phone number (e.g., 123-456-7890)">

<script>
    document.getElementById('phoneNumber').addEventListener('input', function (event) {
        var input = event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, ''); // Remove non-numeric characters
        var formattedInput = input.substring(0, 10).replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3'); // Insert hyphen after the 3rd and 6th digits
        event.target.value = formattedInput;
    });
</script>

Result:

